# Twitter API in Magento

Tags: magento, twitter

I have extension in Magento called Latest Tweet by CREAREGROUP. But the latest tweet on the homepage is empty. This is probably due to the twitter api which has been updated recently. Maybe somebody had same problem and know what is the reason?

Comment: Presumably you managed to update the extension by modifying it as per the linked to tutorial in the below answer which solved your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your extension, you must start with authenticating in order to be allowed to use Twitter API 1.1.

This will help to do so :
http://www.webdevdoor.com/php/authenticating-twitter-feed-timeline-oauth/